# Using Texture1D instead of uniforms

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm using a color palette of 5 colors in my game, and every time I am passing every single color as a `uniform vec3` to the program. Would it be more efficient if I was using a one dimensional texture that contains all 5 colors (15 floats in the texture)?

That's just one of the situations where I would like to do this kind of thing. Another would be to send all the matrices/variables at once to the shader program. I seems a little bit inefficient to send every variable, one at the time, every time I want to render. Would it be better to group them all in a single Texture and send them all at once?

Is there maybe another, even more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If is sufficient to set the uniform variables once. Note uniform variables are stored in the default uniform block.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a micro-optimization. Sending 15 * 4 = 60 bytes to a shader is not causing you any slowdowns, at least compared to your geometry, textures, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be more efficient if I was using a one dimensional texture that contains all 5 colors (15 floats in the texture)?

No, texture reads are most likely going to have less performance, but in your case it shouldn't make much difference.

> Is there maybe another, even more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Well, if they are always the same as you say, then just put them as constants in shaders.

> That's just one of the situations where I would like to do this kind of thing. Another would be to send all the matrices/variables at once to the shader program. I seems a little bit inefficient to send every variable, one at the time, every time I want to render. Would it be better to group them all in a single Texture and send them all at once?

Modifying textures is not going to be any faster then setting a few uniforms.

And if you are going to use your matrices per-vertex or per-fragment, then it will cause a lot of texture reads. That might actually cause a significant performance drop, depending on the amount of vertices/fragments/matrices you have. And even if that texture data ends up in L1 texture cache, it still won't outperform uniform reads.

If you don't want to send all the variables independently, you could use Uniform Buffer Objects.

Comment: That's a great point, but what if I wanted to modify the color palette at some point?

Comment: @RossMyhovych Modify between draw calls? Then the point about uniform access being faster still stands. If you to modify it between app runs then you can just precompile the shaders.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will checkout the uniform buffer objects!